# TabBar + iOS 6 + iPad tabBar disappears

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios6, tabbarcontroller

I have iPad app which works fine on iOS 5. My app root viewController implements UITabBarDelegate and UINavigationControllerDelegate. But on iOS 6 i can see tabBar only once - for the first run. At the second. third etc. runs tabBar disappears. So WFT? %-)

Here's my AppDelegate's applicationDidFinishLaunching:application:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication*)application
{
...
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        CGRect mainViewFrame = _window.frame;
        CGRect statusBarFrame = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame;
        mainViewFrame.origin.y = CGRectGetHeight(statusBarFrame);
        mainViewFrame.size.height -= CGRectGetHeight(statusBarFrame);
        [self padMainController].view.frame = mainViewFrame;

        [_window setRootViewController:[self padMainController]];
    }
...
}
```

Here's padMainController header's snippet:

```
@interface LTPadMainController : LTAutorotateController <UINavigationControllerDelegate, UITabBarDelegate>
```

And LTAutorotateController's snippet:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return ((UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad && UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation)) || (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone && UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation)));
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

Comment: This works fine if project is built in Xcode 4.4 with armv6 v7. And my app fails after build in Xcode 4.5

Comment: shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation is deprecated in iOS 6. What do you mean by first run, second run etc?

Comment: i use shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation for iOS 5 devices.First run is the first run from Xcode. If i try to Run app after first running again, tabBar doesn't appear.